# when im using facebook wall post it give me error

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-access-token

[image: this type of error: length cannot be zero]
When im using Mark Hagan Facebook wall post source code it give me error like length cannot be zero.

im trying to facebook wall post using users. 
here is my code please help me, what is the issue in this code..?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using Facebook;

namespace PayPalAPISample
{
    public partial class facebooksync : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckAuthorization();
        }

        private void CheckAuthorization()
        {
            string app_id = "App Id";
            string app_secret = "App Secret";
            string scope = "publish_actions,manage_pages";

            if (Request["code"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect(string.Format(
                    "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}",
                    app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope));
            }
            else
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}",
                    app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope, Request["code"].ToString(), app_secret);

                HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
                using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                    string vals = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    foreach (string token in vals.Split('&'))
                    {
                        //meh.aspx?token1=steve&token2=jake&...
                        tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf("=")),
                            token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf("=") - 1));
                    }
                }
                string access_token = tokens["access_token"];
                var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);
                client.Post("/me/feed", new { message = "markhagan.me video tutorial" });
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Help !!!. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need to check What is the value assigned to `token`. Does it have `=` in it?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i dont know im using others source code. this code is working in that tutorial. but do not work in me.

Comment: You need to debug the code and check the value of `token` variable. It doesn't matter whose code it is, debugging always helps.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya no anytype of special character in my token

Comment: That's where the issue is. `token.IndexOf("=)` returns -1 that's why `token.SubString` throws this exception. Token are expected to be `token1=Steve` format as per the comments in the code.

Comment: The access token return format has changed with API v2.4, it is now returned in a JSON data structure, so you need to parse it accordingly.